# Whitelabel Error Page when trying to load index.jsp

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat

I am trying to open a simple index.jsp page which contains a form, but I'm getting this, and I can't figure out why. Project is built using Spring Initializr
[image]

[image: file structure]
This is what the file structure looks like

[image: The application.properties file]

This is the pom.xml page, I've looked at some questions regarding a similar issue and some suggest commenting out some scopes, but I tried that with no effect

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.booksmanagement</groupId>
<artifactId>Books</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Books</name>
<description>Books</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any resource at the root of the service and `server.error.whitelabel` is enabled by default. You could disable it using the following configuration

```
server:
  error:
    whitelabel:
      # disable while label page
      enabled: false
```

Comment: on the pom file?

Comment: Also I want the index.jsp page to be displayed, not a blank error page

Comment: in the `application.yml`. Not sure about jsp but you could customize white label https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page